# mvc - How to assign a value to a partial view property from withing its parent view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a View A, View B, and a View _C.

View _C is a partial view that is rendered inside of View A and B:

View A:

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;">

    <div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/_C.cshtml", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "WithRedirect", "true" } });
    </div>

</div>
```

View B

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;">

    <div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/_C.cshtml", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "WithRedirect", "false" } });
    </div>

</div>
```

View C(partial view) - code fragment:

```
.
.

<td style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control k-textbox checkError", placeholder = "Enter current password" } })
</td> 
.
.
```

When rendering partial view, I need to set a flag "WithRedirect" to refer to it later in the controller to decide if I need to redirect to another view or not:

```
string withRedirect = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("WithRedirect") ? this.ViewData["WithRedirect"].ToString() : string.Empty;
```

if(WithRedirect.Equals("true")
    return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Page1"));
else
    return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Page2"));

When debugging the controller, `WithRedirect` variable is an empty string.

What am I doing wrong and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your partial view(`_C.cshtml`), you can read the value from `ViewDataDictionary` and set to an input field inside a `form`. When you submit the form, this value will be also submitted. You can have a parameter in your http post action method which will receive this input field value and using that you can conditionally redirect to page1 or page 2.

```
@model LoginViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Home")) 
{
    <input type="hidden" name="withRedirect" value="@ViewData["WithRedirect"]" />
    @Html.LabelFor(f=>f.Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Password )
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

and now in your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login (LoginViewModel model,bool withRedirect)
{
   //to do : Do something
   if(withRedirect)
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Index","Page1"); 
   } 
   return RedirectToAction("Index","Page2"); 
}
```